# from python_speech_features import mfcc (Import "python_speech_features" could not be resolved)

Tags: python, mfcc

I am trying to run this line of code:
`from python_speech_features import mfcc`

I have already imported python speech features:
`Requirement already satisfied: python_speech_features in...`

However, I am getting this error: Import "python_speech_features" could not be resolved PylancereportMissingImports

I tried importing again, I've tried looking for similar problems, but I couldn't find anything